# Sign Up layout in android

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I have created a sign up layout as image below.

[image]

Does this part of code looked bad since the `dp` I used for the floating button are quite large.

```
   android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
```

If yes, how can I change it ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:id="@+id/imgProfilePicture"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                app:civ_border_width="1dp"
                app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimary"/>


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                app:fabSize="mini"
                android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:elevation="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/camera" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgProfilePicture"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/textViewUserId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="USER ID "/>

    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
              android:id="@+id/editTextUserId"
    />

    <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/textViewUserName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="USERNAME "/>

    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
              android:id="@+id/editTextUsername"
    />


    <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/textViewPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="PASSWORD "/>

    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
              android:id="@+id/editTextUserPassword"
    />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

        <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:id="@+id/textViewCourse"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="COURSE "/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:id="@+id/textViewPhoneNum"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="PHONE NUMBER "/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Spinner android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                 android:id="@+id/spinner"/>


        <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                  android:id="@+id/editTextPhoneNum"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not that bad, but in this case you might have to test it in different screen sizes Android devices, to see if it fits exactly where you want.

In my opinion, better approach is to use `FrameLayout` instead of using relative layout. By using frame layout, you can use gravity center | bottom and thereby removing `marginTop`.

The code goes like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
         android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
         android:id="@+id/imgProfilePicture"
         android:layout_width="110dp"
         android:layout_height="130dp"
         app:civ_border_width="1dp"
         app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimary"
         android:layout_gravity="center"/>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgProfilePicture"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:elevation="2dp"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

And this `marginLeft` 50dp is because , width if your `circleImageView` is 110, so 50 is approximately half where you want it.